# Boost Assign empty list

Tags: list, boost, assign

I want to boost::assign a list to an empty value.
Something like:

```
using namespace boost::assign;
std::list<int> myList = list_of<int>();
```

The reason that I want to do that is that I have a map of lists that I want to initialise and one of the lists in the map is empty.
So I actually want to:

```
std::map<int, std::list<int> > myMap = 
    (map_list_of(0, list_of<int>())
                (1, list_of<int>(1)(2))
                (3, list_of<int>(99));
```

Comment: What about using `std::list<int>()` instead of `list_of<int>()`?

Comment: Thanks tibur, I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::list<int>()` instead of `list_of<int>()`:

```
std::map<int, std::list<int> > myMap = 
    (map_list_of(0, std::list<int>())
                (1, list_of<int>(1)(2))
                (3, list_of<int>(99));
```

Comment: this does not work if the first call has list_of and one of the subsequent call has std::list<int>(). Any work around to this?